# Cappuccino development in windows

Tags: cappuccino

can i do cappucino development in 100% windows without apache?

thanks

Comment: @Elrik Lillebo: funny that your LMGTFY link has actually created a recursion, since this post appears #1 in google results, nice!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a webserver to use Cappuccino, it runs completely client side. You may need linux or mac os x in order to use some of the tools though.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is probably best answered by researching http://cappuccino.org/.

Answer (score 0):

That is possible by using Cygwin, maybe this thread can help http://groups.google.com/group/objectivej/browse_thread/thread/4515ac62e9ca0c80?pli=1